# What is the difference between id and tagname?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

An Interviewer asked this question in selenium webdriver
Please let me know the answer of this question

Thanks
Srinu Marri

Comment: that is pure html question you can learn more in : http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Answer (score 2):

#### Tags

are HTML elements, like

> `<div>, <ul> , <p> , <h1> , etc`

#### Id's

are **ATTRIBUTES** of tag names.  For example:

a `<div>`  tag can be given an id:

```
<div id='firstdiv' >
```

or a class name:

```
<div class="firstdiv">
```

Answer (score 1):

### ID

Identify uniquely HTML elements.  Even if you add more than one ID inside a html  page, the DOM object will render all elements even with the same ids, but if selected by `JavaScript` or `selenium` only will select the first one that is rendered.

E.g:
`findElements(By.id("id")`, Selenium will return an element with this id attribute that are present immediately after the page loads.

### tagname

Works just like class elements. Can identify a element behavior or even a constant markup. The DOM object can handle with multiples elements and even scripts tags.

E.g: `findElements(By.tagName("table")`, Selenium will return an array of all the tables that are present immediately after the page loads.

Comment: Ids **ought** to be unique (Selenium assumes they will be), but they don't have to be.

Comment: @AndrewRegan  thanks !! It was ambiguous. Just updated the answer.